# ORA-00001: unique constraint (AOBHASYSTEM.SYS_C00157383783917) violated

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

> Error starting at line: 14 in command Insert into TABLENAME (COLUMNNAMES) values (AOBHASYSTEM. SEQUENCENAME.NEXTVAL,INPUT FOR OTHER COLUMNS) Error report -ORA-00001: unique constraint (AOBHASYSTEM.SYS_C00157383783917) violeted

According to this error I understand  that here the sequence is causing the main issue as when I'm trying to use the `SEQUENCENAME.NEXTVAL` for inserting the PK value because the `NEXTVAL` is already present in the table.

Can anyone please help me how can I set this sequence value to the max(PK)+1 that is present in DB TABLE to avoid this issue.

I have one solution but that is too lengthy to be genuine by using INCREMENT BY operation with the difference. Can I get any smooth solution for the same please .

FYI.. I'm using ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER tool.

Comment: Did you, or somebody, give ALL your sequences the name SEQUENCENAME? That's not good. Also, the leading blank space is weird, if it's actually in the error message, although probably not the source of the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle 9 - Resetting Sequence to match the state of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426647/oracle-9-resetting-sequence-to-match-the-state-of-the-table)

Comment: @Jonathan, that's - in Oracle - an impossible mission. Two objects can't share the same name, so - no, nobody named **all** sequences SEQUENCENAME. I second what MT0 suggests (a sequence should be reset).

Comment: Hello @JonathanZ, No the sequence name is not like this I just made the changes on the name for Posting in this public platform. Sorry for the confusion but in the original error it's not leading to any space error or anything

Comment: Hello @MT0, Thanks for the suggestion. I have made this solution before but it seems like bit lengthy to workout . So searching for a quicker one if that can help instead of using this step by step detailed format please . Many thanks Guys!

Comment: A "quicker" one is to **drop** the sequence and then **create** a new one, starting with desired value.

Comment: @Littlefoot - At this moment I'll avoid this drop option because again I have do grant all type of access according to the needs /roles that has been defined previously. But ofcourse this can be one of the solution if we want to go for in some point if needed . Thanks for the input !

Comment: In that case, apply that *long* procedure. If you did that 15 hours ago (when you asked the question), you'd have it up and running for at least 14 hours and 50 minutes.

Comment: Yes I have done that one only before so haven't waste anything . No worries at all ! The intention here to ask the question is finding the best solution that is having more impact in terms of maintaining these cases .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a RESTART, eg

```
SQL> create sequence seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         3

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         4

SQL> alter sequence seq restart minvalue 200;

Sequence altered.

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
       200

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
       201

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
       202
```

Comment: Hello, this is what I was searching for . Thank you so much for this . I did tried with `...restart with 200;` and that doesn't work so was thinking might be doing it wrong.But anyhow something came up . Thanks again!